# typescript async await in nested function call

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get 'assigned suspect' out of the callbacks, but it shows undefined, however it works in if statement. It's related to await/async. please help

```
export async function getMatches(target:string) {
    let suspect : any
    await iam.listUsers(async function(err,data){
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else    {
        for (let users of data.Users) {
            let params : any = {
                UserName: users.UserName
               }
                await iam.listAccessKeys(params, function(err, data) {
                let keys : any = data.AccessKeyMetadata[0]
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else{
                if(keys){
                   // console.log(keys.AccessKeyId)
                    if (keys.AccessKeyId == target)
                        suspect = keys.UserName
                        console.log(suspect)
                }
            }

            });
        }
        console.log(suspect)
    }
});
return suspect
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, await only works with returning promise, so make them promise to await and handle resolve

```
export async function getMatches(target:string) {
    let suspect : any
    let t : any
    await new Promise((resolve:any)=>{iam.listUsers(async function(err,data){
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else    {
       resolve( t = data.Users)
    }});
})  
let ee = t;

await new Promise((resolve:any)=>{for(let users of ee){
        //console.log(users)
    let params : any = {
        UserName: users.UserName
    }
    iam.listAccessKeys(params, function(err, data) {
    let keys : any = data.AccessKeyMetadata[0]
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else{
        if(keys){
                   // console.log(keys.AccessKeyId)
                if (keys.AccessKeyId == target)
                       resolve(suspect = keys.UserName)
                       // console.log(suspect)
                }
            }

            });



}})
console.log(suspect)
}
```